# How to split a string in apex

Tags: apex

A text field (let say field name is 'Testfield') in account has multiple values like

**input** : "**1234-test-email;4567-test1,test2-email,call**"

I want to split the values and store them in another variable like integer or string(what ever the variable is).

**output**  this need to be used split method

1)1234-test-email,

2)4567-test1-email,

3)4567-test2-email,

4)4567-test1-call,

5)4567-test2-call,

I want solution for this using apex class and don't have no idea how to start. Can any one please help me in this?

```
string str = '1234-test-email;4567-test1,test2-email,call';
List<String> configString = str.split(';');
List<String> groupNames = new List<String>();
for(String strTemp : configString){
    List<String> eachSetting = strTemp.split('-');
    String groupNameTemp = '';
    String groupNameTemp1='';
    for(String eachConfig : eachSetting){              
        List<String> eachconfigValue = eachConfig.split(',');       
        if(eachconfigValue.size() == 1){
            groupNameTemp += eachconfigValue;
            groupNameTemp += '-';           
            groupNameTemp1 = groupNameTemp.removeEnd('-');
            System.debug('groupNameTemp1' +groupNameTemp1);
        }        else{
            for(String eachConfigSep : eachconfigValue){
                 groupNameTemp += eachConfigSep;
                 System.debug('groupNameTemp' +groupNameTemp);      
                 groupNameTemp += '-';                
                 groupNameTemp1 = groupNameTemp.removeEnd('-');
                 System.debug('groupNameTemp1' +groupNameTemp1); 
            }
              groupNames.add(groupNameTemp1);    
        }    }
       groupNames.add(groupNameTemp1);
       system.debug('groupNameTemp'+groupNameTemp1);    }
    System.debug('groupNames' +groupNames);
    List<String> splitstr = new List<String>();
    for(String st :groupNames){
        string sl=st.remove('(');
        string sll=sl.remove(')');
        splitstr.add(sll);}
        System.debug('splitstr' +splitstr);
```

Comment: This question is still missing important details. What determines how the output is supposed to be built? What is the significance of `;`, `-`, and `,`? If you don't provide enough detail, then it's hard for people to give meaningful answers. Also, the vast majority of us here are volunteers with very limited time. The easier you make it for people to help you, the more answers you'll tend to get (conversely, the harder you make it, the fewer answers).

Answer (score 3):

The [String class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm) has the `split()` method, which does what you're looking for.

The result is a `List<String>`

Comment: yes but i can split only once but i need to split it like 4 times need to use nested loops

Comment: @TrinadhVadlamani Why do you think you need to split 4 times? A single call to `split()` will give you `[1234-test-email, 4567-test1, test2-email, call]` (assuming the semicolon was a typo and is actually a comma, though splitting on `;|,` should work). If that's not what you're looking for, then you need to edit your question to give a more precise example and include more details.

Comment: my input is "T6302-Email-en_us;K7676836-Email,liveCall-en_US,sp" and output need to be like below i'm need to split and concatinate other values as follows           T6302-Email-en_us,                                                                                          K7676836-Email-en_us                                                                                    
,K7676836-email-sp ,                                                                                              K7676836-liveCall-en_US,                                      K7676836-liveCall-en_US,K7676836-livecall-sp

Comment: @TrinadhVadlamani you need to edit your question to include that information, and include a better description of what you're trying to do. Something like "take the parts after the semicolon and concatenate each one to the part before the semicolon. e.g. a-b, a-c, a-d"

Comment: now i edited the question can u please provide answer?

Comment: i have given the code i hope now it will be easy to understabd

Answer (score 0):

Derek has provided the correct answer, here is the implementation for you to understand it appropriately.
We can split function to split multiple parameters at a time.

```apex
String s = '234-test-email;4567-test1,test2-email';
String[] tokens = s.split('[;,]');
system.debug(tokens);
```

here is the output :
[image]

Comment: can u please recheck the question and update